# Struggling to use $fetch instead of usefetch in Nuxt :

Tags: typescript, laravel, frontend, nuxt.js, fetch-api

**This is the code I was using for the authentication front-end, but 2 days ago the following error appeared and I was asking myself how to fix the warning... but I couldn't figure it out how to solve it.**

> Warning:
>
> [nuxt] [useFetch] Component is already mounted, please use $fetch instead. See https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching**

**My Code :**

```
import type { UseFetchOptions } from "nuxt/app";
 
import { useRequestHeaders } from "nuxt/app";
 
export function useApiFetch<T>(path: string, options: UseFetchOptions<T> = {}) {
    let headers: any = {
        accept: "application/json",
        referer: "http://localhost:3000",
    };
 
    const token = useCookie("XSRF-TOKEN");
 
    if (token.value) {
        headers["X-XSRF-TOKEN"] = token.value as string;
    }
 
    if (process.server) {
        headers = {
            ...headers,
 
            ...useRequestHeaders(["cookie"]),
        };
    }
 
    return useFetch("http://localhost:8000" + path, {
        credentials: "include",
 
        watch: false,
 
        ...options,
 
        headers: {
            ...headers,
 
            ...options?.headers,
        },
    });
}
```

I tried to disable TypeScript and eventually I tried to implement `$fetch` but in the return object I have have many errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useApiFetch } from '~/file'
const { data, error, execute } = useApiFetch(
  '/api/path', 
  { immediate: false }
)
const doFetch = async () => {
  await execute()
}
</script>
```

see this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njsGVmcWviY&ab_channel=AlexanderLichter

Answer (score 0):

Use fetch. Modify your code to this:

```
import { useRequestHeaders } from "nuxt/app"

export async function useApiFetch(path, options) {
    const config = useRuntimeConfig()

    let headers = {
        accept: "application/json",
        referer: "http://localhost:3000"
    }

    const token = useCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');

    if (token.value) {
        headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = token.value;
    }

    if (process.server) {
        headers = {
            ...headers,
            ...useRequestHeaders(["cookie"]),
        }

    }

    let data, error

    try {
        data = await $fetch(config.public.apiUrl + path, {
            credentials: "include",
            watch: false,
            ...options,
            headers: {
                ...headers,
                ...options?.headers
            }
        })
    }
    catch (e) {
        error = e
    }
    return { data: ref(data), error: ref(error) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create fetch with default settings https://github.com/unjs/ofetch?tab=readme-ov-file#%EF%B8%8F-create-fetch-with-default-options

For example:

```js
export const $api = $fetch.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000',
  credentials: "include",
  watch: false,

  onRequest({ options }) {
    let headers: Record<string, string> = {
        accept: "application/json",
        referer: "http://localhost:3000",
    };
 
    const token = useCookie("XSRF-TOKEN");
 
    if (token.value) {
        headers["X-XSRF-TOKEN"] = token.value as string;
    }
 
    if (process.server) {
        headers = {
            ...headers,
            ...(options.headers || {}),
            ...useRequestHeaders(["cookie"]),
        };
    }
    options.headers = headers
  },
})
```

Then call `$api()` in your project.